# Do all language bindings of Selenium support same functionality?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am reading Selenium documentation (eg http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) and notice that some examples are not available in JavaScript. Is it due to incomplete documentation or is certain functionality not implemented in JavaScript binding? Shall I learn Selenium using Java binding or would any binding be OK?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they do support same functionality. I remember that I was trying to figure out what to do from vs options on our mvc project. Just a great product with bad documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Selenium JavaScript documentation in below link:-

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html

The above link contains all modules cover.

Additionally, they have put up all details regarding changes they have done version to version.